failed to analyze machine learning models with teachable machine on android studio use kotlin
I have a problem when I analyze the photo. I have 3 models which is Cancer, Non-cancer, and unknown. when I try to analyze the result is always "unknown" does anyone know how to solve it? I tried to change my code and asking ai too and still stuck.
here is my code
ImageClassifierHelper

class ImageClassifierHelper(
    private var threshold: Float = 0.5f, // Tingkatkan threshold
    private var maxResult: Int = 3,
    private val modelName: String = "model_unquant.tflite",
    val context: Context,
    val classifierListener: ClassifierListener?
) {
    interface ClassifierListener {
        fun onError(error: String)
        fun onResults(result: MutableList<Category>?)
    }

    private var imageClassifier: ModelUnquant? = null

    init {
        setupImageClassifier()
    }

    private fun setupImageClassifier() {
        try {
            imageClassifier = ModelUnquant.newInstance(context)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            classifierListener?.onError(context.getString(R.string.failed))
            Log.e(TAG, e.message.toString())
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "ImageClassifierHelper"
    }

    // Tambahkan daftar label yang sesuai dengan model Anda
    private val labels = listOf("Non-Cancer", "Cancer", "Unknown")

    fun classifyStaticImage(imageUri: Uri) {
        if (imageClassifier == null) {
            setupImageClassifier()
        }

        // Mengonversi Uri ke Bitmap
        val bitmap = uriToBitmap(context.contentResolver, imageUri)
            ?: run {
                classifierListener?.onError("Failed to decode image")
                return
            }
        if (bitmap == null) {
            classifierListener?.onError("Failed to decode image")
            return
        }

        val resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 224, 224, true)

        // Mengonversi Bitmap ke TensorImage
        val tensorImage = TensorImage(DataType.FLOAT32)
        tensorImage.load(resizedBitmap)

        // Membuat TensorBuffer untuk input
        val inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, 224, 224, 3), DataType.FLOAT32)
        inputFeature0.loadBuffer(tensorImage.buffer)

        // Menjalankan inferensi model dan mendapatkan hasil
        val outputs = imageClassifier?.process(inputFeature0)
        val outputFeature0 = outputs?.outputFeature0AsTensorBuffer

        // Mengonversi hasil ke daftar kategori
        val probability = outputFeature0?.let { tensorBuffer ->
            tensorBuffer.floatArray.mapIndexed { index, value ->
                Category(labels.getOrElse(index) { "Unknown" }, value)
            }.filter { it.score >= threshold } // Filter berdasarkan threshold
                .toMutableList()
        }

        classifierListener?.onResults(probability)
    }

    private fun uriToBitmap(contentResolver: ContentResolver, uri: Uri): Bitmap? {
        return try {
            val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            null
        }
    }
}



